# How do I get rid off undesirable Java version?

Tags: java, openjdk

I need to replace Java JDK 11 with 8 because that's the only Java version that works with Buildozer.

11 is installed on my machine:

```
openjdk 11.0.5 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

when I run `sudo apt-get remove openjdk-11-jdk` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openjdk-11-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by running: `sudo apt-get remove openjdk-*`